# Gorilla mux reuse/restart server after a shutdown

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

I am setting up an http server in a separate goroutine. This goroutine will set up a new server on a signal. However, after a shutdown request, I cannot restart that, Here is the code

```
for {
       select {
       case <-m.start:
           fmt.Println("Start the server now")

           go func() {
               err := m.ListenAndServe()
               if err != nil {
                   fmt.Println(err)
               }
           }()
       case <-m.stop:
           fmt.Println("Stop the server now")
           go func() {

               ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
               err := m.Shutdown(ctx)
               fmt.Println("Error is :", err)
               if err != nil {
                   fmt.Println(err)
               }
               cancel()
           }()
       }
   }
```

I am controlling this goroutine through separate handlers externally. In the documentation, it is mentioned that the server may not be reused after a shutdown. Is there any alternative?

Comment: share full code

Comment: There is yes, create a new `http.Server`.